# Cosmos DB Emulator hangs when pumping continuation token, segmented query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have just added a new feature to an app I'm building. It uses the same working Cosmos/Table storage code that other features use to query and pump results segments from the Cosmos DB Emulator via the Tables API.

The emulator is running with:

```
/EnableTableEndpoint /PartitionCount=50
```

This is because I read that the emulator defaults to 5 unlimited containers and/or 25 limited and since this is a Tables API app, the table containers are created as unlimited.

The table being queried is the 6th to be created and contains just 1 document.

It either takes around 30 seconds to run a simple query and "trips" my `Too Many Requests` error handling/retry in the process, or hangs seemingly forever and no results are returned, the emulator has to be shut down.

My understanding is that with 50 partitions I can make 10 unlimited tables, collections since each is "worth" 5. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/emulator-command-line-parameters#set-partitioncount).

I have tried with rate limiting on and off, and jacked the RU/s to 10,000 on the table. It always fails to query this one table. The data, including the files on disk, has been cleared many times.

It seems like a bug in the emulator. Note that the "Sorry..." error that I would expect to see upon creation of the 6th unlimited table, as per the docs, is never encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching to a real Cosmos DB instance on Azure, this is looking like a problem with my dodgy code.

**Confirmed**: my dodgy code.

Stand down everyone. As you were.